# jQuery Fileupload Angular Cancel Event

Tags: jquery, angularjs, jquery-file-upload

I am working on jQuery file upload with Angular using this plugin http://blueimp.github.io/jQuery-File-Upload/angularjs.html

All works fine except cancel button, It cancel the file but I am getting error in console that looks like this https://www.dropbox.com/s/nup2vkwfsfslqcu/cancel_error.PNG

I have app.js

```
(function () {
    'use strict';



    var isOnGitHub = window.location.hostname === 'blueimp.github.io',
        url = isOnGitHub ? '//jquery-file-upload.appspot.com/' : '/api/imageUpload';

    angular.module('myApp', [
        'blueimp.fileupload'
    ])
        .config([
            '$httpProvider', 'fileUploadProvider',
            function ($httpProvider, fileUploadProvider) {
                delete $httpProvider.defaults.headers.common['X-Requested-With'];
                fileUploadProvider.defaults.redirect = window.location.href.replace(
                    /\/[^\/]*$/,
                    '/cors/result.html?%s'
                );
                if (isOnGitHub) {
                    // Demo settings:
                    angular.extend(fileUploadProvider.defaults, {
                        // Enable image resizing, except for Android and Opera,
                        // which actually support image resizing, but fail to
                        // send Blob objects via XHR requests:
                        disableImageResize: /Android(?!.*Chrome)|Opera/
                            .test(window.navigator.userAgent),
                        maxFileSize: 5000000,
                        acceptFileTypes: /(\.|\/)(gif|jpe?g|png)$/i
                    });
                }
            }
        ])

        .controller('DemoFileUploadController', [
            '$scope', '$http', '$filter', '$window',
            function ($scope, $http) {
                $scope.options = {
                    url: url
                };

                $scope.setCover = function () {

                    var fileId;
                    $('input[type="radio"]').each(function () {
                        if ($(this).is(":checked")) { fileId = $(this).attr('id'); }
                    });

                    return $http({
                        url: "/home/SetCoverImage/?fileId=" + fileId,
                        method: "post"
                    }).then(
                           function () {
                               console.log("succcess");
                           },
                           function () {
                               console.log("error");
                           }
                       );
                };


            }
        ])

        .controller('FileDestroyController', [
            '$scope', '$http',
            function ($scope, $http) {
                var file = $scope.file,
                    state;


                if (file.name) {



                    file.$destroy = function () {

                        state = 'pending';
                        return $http({
                            url: "/api/imageupload/?id=" + file.id,
                            method: "delete"
                        }).then(
                            function () {
                                state = 'resolved';
                                $scope.clear(file);
                            },
                            function () {
                                state = 'rejected';
                            }
                        );
                    };

                    file.$cancel = function () {
                        console.log("cancel individual");
                        $scope.clear(file);
                    };
                }

            }
        ]);

}());
```

And html defined as

```
<link href="~/Content/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="~/Content/css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="~/Content/css/jquery.fileupload.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="~/Content/css/jquery.fileupload-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<style>
    /* Hide Angular JS elements before initializing */
    .ng-cloak {
        display: none;
    }
</style>
@section scripts{

    <script src="~/Scripts/js/vendor/jquery.ui.widget.js"></script>
    <script src="http://blueimp.github.io/JavaScript-Load-Image/js/load-image.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://blueimp.github.io/JavaScript-Canvas-to-Blob/js/canvas-to-blob.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/js/jquery.iframe-transport.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/js/jquery.fileupload.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/js/jquery.fileupload-process.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/js/jquery.fileupload-image.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/js/jquery.fileupload-validate.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/lib/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/js/jquery.fileupload-angular.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/js/app.js"></script>
}

<div class="form-group row">
    <div data-ng-app="myApp" data-ng-controller="DemoFileUploadController" data-file-upload="options" data-ng-class="{'fileupload-processing': processing() || loadingFiles}">
        <!-- Redirect browsers with JavaScript disabled to the origin page -->
        <noscript><input type="hidden" name="redirect" value="http://www.myapp.com"></noscript>
        <!-- The fileupload-buttonbar contains buttons to add/delete files and start/cancel the upload -->
        <div class="row fileupload-buttonbar">
            <div class="col-lg-7">
                <!-- The fileinput-button span is used to style the file input field as button -->
                <span class="btn btn-success fileinput-button" ng-class="{disabled: disabled}">
                    <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></i>
                    <span>Add files...</span>
                    <input type="file" name="files[]" multiple ng-disabled="disabled">
                </span>

                <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning cancel" data-ng-click="cancel()">
                    <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-ban-circle"></i>
                    <span>Cancel upload</span>
                </button>
                <!-- The global file processing state -->
                <span class="fileupload-process"></span>
            </div>
            <!-- The global progress state -->
            <div class="col-lg-5 fade" data-ng-class="{in: active()}">
                <!-- The global progress bar -->
                <div class="progress progress-striped active" data-file-upload-progress="progress()"><div class="progress-bar progress-bar-success" data-ng-style="{width: num + '%'}"></div></div>
                <!-- The extended global progress state -->
                <div class="progress-extended">&nbsp;</div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <!-- The table listing the files available for upload/download -->
        <table class="table table-striped files ng-cloak">
            <tr data-ng-repeat="file in queue" data-ng-class="{'Uploading': file.$processing()}">
                <td data-ng-switch data-on="!!file.thumbnailUrl">
                    <div class="preview" data-ng-switch-when="true">
                        <a data-ng-href="{{file.url}}" title="{{file.name}}" download="{{file.name}}" data-gallery><img data-ng-src="{{file.thumbnailUrl}}" alt=""></a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="preview" data-ng-switch-default data-file-upload-preview="file"></div>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <p class="name" data-ng-switch data-on="!!file.url">
                        <span data-ng-switch-when="true" data-ng-switch data-on="!!file.thumbnailUrl">
                            <a data-ng-switch-when="true" data-ng-href="{{file.url}}" title="{{file.name}}" download="{{file.name}}" data-gallery>{{file.name}}</a>
                            <a data-ng-switch-default data-ng-href="{{file.url}}" title="{{file.name}}" download="{{file.name}}">{{file.name}}</a>
                        </span>
                        <span data-ng-switch-default>{{file.name}}</span>
                    </p>
                    <strong data-ng-show="file.error" class="error text-danger">{{file.error}}</strong>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <p class="size">{{file.size | formatFileSize}}</p>
                    <div class="progress progress-striped active fade" data-ng-class="{pending: 'in'}[file.$state()]" data-file-upload-progress="file.$progress()"><div class="progress-bar progress-bar-success" data-ng-style="{width: num + '%'}"></div></div>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <div>
                        <div class="control-label">
                            <input type="radio" id="{{file.id}}" name="cover" /> <label>Set Cover</label>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary start" data-ng-click="file.$submit()" data-ng-hide="!file.$submit || options.autoUpload" data-ng-disabled="file.$state() == 'pending' || file.$state() == 'rejected'">
                        <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-upload"></i>
                        <span>Start</span>
                    </button>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning cancel" data-ng-click="file.$cancel()" data-ng-show="file.isUploaded">
                        <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-ban-circle"></i>
                        <span>Cancel</span>
                    </button>
                    <button data-ng-controller="FileDestroyController" type="button" class="btn btn-danger destroy" data-ng-click="file.$destroy()" data-ng-hide="!file.$destroy">
                        <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></i>
                        <span>Delete</span>
                    </button>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>


        <div class="form-group row">
            <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-4">
                <button data-ng-click="setCover()" class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Submit</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Did you check that url from error? It seems to point to documentation.

Answer (score 0):

You can try override the `progress` function. It's a provisional fix.

```
fileUploadProvider.defaults.progress = function(e, data) {
  if (e.isDefaultPrevented()) {
    return false;
  }
  if (!data.scope.$$phase) {
    data.scope.$apply();
  }
};
```